# Is there any live example of all Services of feathersJS with code?

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, feathersjs

I want example and code for all the services of feathersJS.

Like

1. find
2. get
3. create
4. update
5. patch
6. remove
7. update

All the services in on app with the help of RethinkDB.

Comment: 1 minute googling https://github.com/feathersjs. Scroll down and look at some code.

Comment: I already visited that! @Phil

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places to find examples.

The RethinkDB section in the feathers databases docs has some examples (especially of find).

https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/rethinkdb.html#querying

And the more general docs section on Services has examples of each type.

https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html

If you know what you are trying to achieve in RethinkDB already then usually you can put options into the `params` argument that gets passed through the database adapter.

Comment: I already read that doc but what I want is all the services In one feathers app